# Numbering color in align environment

Tags: equations, numbering, color, align, labels

I have a long series of equations in an `align` environment and I want to highlight only the last one (final result) using `\color{red}`. However, the label number stays black (unlike to what happen in the `equation` environment). How do I change also the color of the number?

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\colorlabel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \tag{\textcolor{#1}{\theequation}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:equation}
\color{red} a = b + c
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\label{eq:align}
a &= b + c \nonumber
\\
& \colorlabel{red}\color{red} = e + f
\end{align}
Eq~\eqref{eq:equation} shows that referencing using the equation environment gives black text.
Eq~\eqref{eq:align} shows that referencing using the align environment gives colored numbers with black brackets.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Building on jarauh's solution, I am currently using

```
\newcommand{\colorlabel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \tag{\color{#1}{\theequation}}}
```

which, however, keeps the brackets black. Also, when references, the number is colored but not the brackets. This behavior is different from the one shown using `equation` (everything is black when referenced). I would like to have a consistent behavior between them (it would be great to have one single command, without manually modifying the color before/after the equation).

Comment: By the way, you include the same package `amssymb` twice.

Comment: Oops, you are right. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the AMS LaTeX documentation `amsmath.pdf` to see how labels are treated, and I found a way to colour the equation number next to the equation red, while the colour of any reference is unchanged.  All other parts of the `align` environment have to be made red separately.  One thing to note: If you use `\color{red}` within the environment `align`, its effect only reaches until the next `&` or `\\`.  Apparently, all cells in the environment are within different groups.

```
\makeatletter
\definecolor{johnnywalker}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\newcommand{\redlabel}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \global\tag@true%
  \nonumber%
  \gdef\df@tag{\maketag@@@{{\color{johnnywalker}(\theequation)}}\def\@currentlabel{\theequation}}}
\makeatother
```

Then you can use this as follows:

```
\begin{align}
  a &  = b + c
  \\
  \redlabel
  &  = e + f
\end{align}
```

Now, `\ref` and `\eqref` should behave as expected.

### Explanation

The commands `\tag` and `\label` do not create the tag and label immediately.  Instead, everything is deferred until all of the line has been read.  Only then is the tag typeset and the label created.

The code above does the following:

1. Step the counter manually (since we cannot rely on the automatic tag generation)
2. Tell AMSTeX that the tag has been set manually.
3. Tell AMSTeX to not generate an equation number automatically
4. Initialize the command `\df@tag` with content that generates the tag and the label

   2. and 3. I copied from the definition of `\tag@in@align` (the version of `\tag` that is active in `align` environments).  4. comes from the definition of `\make@df@tag@@@` (the command that is responsible for saving the information about the tag and the label).

Comment: It works well, thanks! However, if I reference an equation using `\eqref`, I get double brackets, some in red and some in black. And the behavior is slightly different using `\textcolor{red}{\print@eqnum}}`.

Comment: @Simon I also noted this problem and updated the solution.  If you use `\ref` instead of `\eqref`, then you won't have double brackets.  The problem is that the brackets have to be part of the tag, otherwise they remain black.

Comment: Thanks, but there are 2 minor problems: if I want to use different tags (e.g., `[1]`) I also have to change the command; manually reverting the color can be annoying and the color might not always be the same and I have to remember the color I used. Building on your solution, I am currently using `\newcommand{\colorlabel}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \tag{\textcolor{#1}{\theequation}}}` which, however, keeps the brackets black. I tried redefining `tags` and `ref` but without success.

Comment: @Simon I changed the answer again.